# UICollectionView with row with two columns and other row with one column

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a customer that wants a news page like this

[image]

but with `UICollectionView` I have no idea how to do. I have to use `reusable` element because this page may be contains infinite elements.

Idea ?

Comment: You could subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and just change the cell sizes - spacing, etc.

Comment: Is there some public resource that realize this or from which I can take inspiration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -`(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and set different size for each cell

Comment: Ok, but how can set two cell for a row ?

Comment: check the section/ row and return the width/height of the cell.
If there is enough space for both of them they will be at the same row